# Update all rows in csv with same value using python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update all column values in respective rows using python. I am using the following code.

```
def update_run_id_in_csv(rds_db_conn,test_case_name,file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name))
    for x in df:
        df.loc[x, 'run_id'] = '232323'
        #get_run_id(rds_db_conn,max_13f_query,query)
        df.to_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name, index=False))
    print(df)
```

The issue with this code is I am not getting the output as expected. For e.g. if this is the csv

```
Name,Age,Gender
Pratik,26,Male
Sarvesh,20,Male
```

Then if I want to update the age value with 30 for both rows, my expected output should be

```
Name,Age,Gender
Pratik,30,Male
Sarvesh,30,Male
```

But what I am currently getting with this code is as follows

```
,,Name,Age,Gender
Name,30,
Age,30,
Gender,30,
```

Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Can you write this `df.to_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name, index=False))` outside for loop in your code. Currently you are executing it inside for loop which is incorrect

Comment: Still working the same way.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop here. You can use either `df.loc[:, "Age"] =  30` or simply `df["Age"] = 30`.

Try this :

```
def update_run_id_in_csv(rds_db_conn,test_case_name,file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name))
    df.loc[:, "Age"]= 30 #or df["Age"]= 30
    #get_run_id(rds_db_conn,max_13f_query,query)
    df.to_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name, index=False))
    print(df)
```

##### # Output :

```
      Name  Age Gender
0   Pratik   30   Male
1  Sarvesh   30   Male
```

Comment: This works but I am getting an extra comma at the start in the header as follows ,Name,Age,Gender. How to remove that extra comma?